# Outlook Macro to save attachments from public mailbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the following macro, it all works fine but I would like it to read a public mailbox instead of the inbox, I would also like it to move the emails that have been processed to a different folder:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveSubFolderAttachments()
    On Error GoTo SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err
' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Test") ' Enter correct subfolder name.
    i = 0
' Check subfolder for messages and exit of none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in folder.", vbInformation, _
               "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
                FileName = "S:\SME folder\Registrations\NKC Test Email Extract\" & _
                    Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
        Next Atmt
    Next Item
' Show summary message
    If i > 0 Then
        varResponse = MsgBox("I found " & i & " attached files." _
        & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the S:\SME folder\Registrations\NKC Test Email Extract\ folder." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to view the files now?" _
        , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
' Open Windows Explorer to display saved files if user chooses
        If varResponse = vbYes Then
            Shell "Explorer.exe /e,S:\SME folder\Registrations\NKC Test Email Extract\", vbNormalFocus
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If
' Clear memory
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle Errors
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

By "public mailbox", do you mean another user's mailbox? Use GetSharedDefaultFolder instead of GetDefaultFolder.